# yes/ No : Is there exist disjoint subsets of $A$ and $B$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $m^*( A \cup B) = m^*(A) + m^*(B) ?$

Tags: measure-theory

Is there  exist disjoint subsets of $A$ and $B$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $m^*( A \cup B) = m^*(A) + m^*(B) ?$

My attempt : If I take $A= [-1,1]$ and $B= [-2,2]$

Here $m^*([-1,1]) = 2,  m^*([-2,2]) = 4$

then $m^*( A \cup B) \neq m^*(A) + m^*(B) $

since $m^*( A \cup B) = m^*([-1,1] \cup [-2,2])= m* ([-1,2])= 3$

Comment: Your $A$ and $B$ are not disjoint. Perhaps you want an example of **non-disjoint** sets where this can happen because otherwise it follows from the very definition of measure.

Comment: This would be a more interesting question, but again simple examples still work. Take $A = [0,1]$ and $B = [1,2]$. Evidently the intersection is nonempty and yet the measures still add up as desired.

Comment: @AnuragA Maybe a more challenging question would be to find two sets $A, B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $A\cap B$ is uncountable yet $m^*(A \cup B) = m^*(A) + m^*(B)$.

Comment: Is $m^*$ a measure, or only an outer measure?

Comment: @Bungo outer measure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition a measure is countably additive, so in this case, suppose $\{A_n\}$ is a sequence of pairwise disjoint subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, then:
$$
m^*\Big( \bigcup_n A_n \Big) = \sum_n m^*(A_n).
$$

As an example: Let $A = \mathbb{N}$ and $B = \{ - n \: | \: n \in \mathbb{N} \}$. Evidently, these sets are disjoint and $m^*(A) = m^*(B) = 0$. The union $A \cup B$ are just the integers $\mathbb{Z}$, excluding $0$, which again has measure zero. So:
$$
m^*(A \cup B) = m^*(A) + m^*(B).
$$

Comment: Yes, in fact it is part of the definition (countable additivity). I figured I would just give a specific example, but I should've mentioned this in the answer (which I will now add).

Comment: Doesn't $m^*$ usually denote outer measure, which is only countably subadditive in general? (Of course, additivity holds if all of the sets are measurable.)

Comment: You are right about an outer measure being countably subadditive. I assumed $m^*$ was a measure, however I should've asked the OP if this is what he meant. Now that I think back I believe Rudin used $m^*$ to denote outer measure. In any case my example still holds.